# C# Equivlant of C void?

Tags: c#, c

Hi I have the following sub:

```
static ustr *construct_packet(int ptype, int stype, int argc, ...)

static ustr *construct_subpacket(int sptype, const char *data, int datalen, int lenbyte)
```

I tried the "..." in C# and it just gives me an error of "Type Expected."

I also need to send multiple construct_subpacket's into the construct_packet sub.

What would be the equivalent to these in C#?

Question 2:

I want to pass weird ASCII characters like "char(13)" the box through a string without it being replaced by "?." How do I go about doing such a thing? Or is there no way?

Thanks

Comment: You don't seem to be using `void`.  Are you asking about the C# equivalent to the variable argument list ellipsis `...`?

Comment: Are you trying to call C code from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static string construct_packet(int ptype, int stype, int argc, ...)
static string construct_subpacket(int sptype, string data, int datalen, int lenbyte)
```

Note:

1. You don't really have to pass datalen in C# - unlike with pointers, with strings you always know length of the string by checking the Length property on the string
2. If you want to pass variable number of arguments, you can use "params" keyword. All those arguments have to be the same type

Comment: How would I use any character in the ASCII from 0 - 255 without C# automatic replacing it with the "?" character?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question - C# doesn't replace any characters. You might see '?' instead of a character when you show the string on the screen, but that has nothing to do with C#. Probably those characters are not setup in the system you are using?

Comment: It's like the box characters with ASCII character 13 that is replaces with question marks. And it just shows the "?" characters for non A-Z or 0 - 9, etc... characters that are normal.

Comment: Are you avare, that .NET is completly unicode and when you need to use different encodings, then you need to Encode your string/character apropriately?